# VBA Add CommandButton With Code - Runtime Error 9

Tags: vba, excel

In my Workbook i have a CommandButton which opens a New Workbook and adds a CommandButton.

My Problem now is, that i always get the run time Error 9 when i click the Button.

This is my Code for the new Workbook:

```
Sub PM_Controlling_Click()
    Dim relativePath As String

    Workbooks.Add
    relativeString = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test2"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativeString & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    Call Import_UserForm
    Call Import_Modul
    Call Working_Structur
End Sub
```

This i my Import Code:

```
Sub Import_UserForm
    Workbooks("Test2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Desktop\Code_Samples\UserForm1.frm"
End Sub

Sub Import_Modul
    Workbooks("Test2.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Desktop\Code_Samples\AddAZ.bas"
End Sub
```

And here is my Working_Structur Modul where i try to add the Button with Code:

```
Sub Working_Structur()
    Dim btn1 As Object
    Dim Code As String

    Set btn1 = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
    , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=105, Top:=175, Width:=50, Height:=25)
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Caption = "Watch"
    btn1.Name = "Watch AZ"
    Code = "Sub Watch_Click()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Call Watch_AZ_Sheet" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub"     

    ' Next Part causes the run time error
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeModule 
        .insertlines .CountOfLines + 1, Code
    End With
```

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**

The error appears in Sub Working_Structure, the Line

**With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeModule**

causes the error.

Comment: Could you please mention on which line of code you are getting the error?

Comment: I mention it in the Working_Structur with a Comment .. but i will add it in a little more details.

Comment: To check:  As per the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224302(v=office.11).aspx), have you remembered to "select the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility** check box in the **References** dialog box (**Tools** menu) in the Visual Basic Editor."  Also, have you considered adding an Form Control button and using [`Shape.OnAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/shape-onaction-property-excel) to point at an existing Macro?

Comment: Instead of multiplying code over a number of data workbooks, why creating an add-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that Subscript out of range `runtime error 9` is thrown when part of what is being referenced does not exist or is undefined.

Maybe the cause of the error is `ActiveSheet.Name` is not being the VBAComponent name

Please check the names of the VBA components matching your sheet actual name.

Below example throws error since the sheet name `ActualSheetName` is not the component name `Sheet1`

[image]

Renaming the Component name will fix the issue. Something like :

[image]

**Update:**
You can directly use the codename property of worksheet in the code.

[Worksheet.CodeName MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel)

```
With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
```